# xcode-select: error: no developer tools were found, and no install could be requested (perhaps no UI is present)

Tags: ios, xcode

When I tried to install Xcode command line tools with

```
xcode-select --install
```

I got the error

```
xcode-select: error: no developer tools were found, and no install could be requested (perhaps no UI is present), please install manually from 'developer.apple.com'
```

I found a similar question [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/21448), but this does not work for me.
Any ideas? Thanks first.

Answer (score 1):

if you are still seeing this issue, try these steps:

1. Install `Xcode` from within App Store
2. Run from an user with access to a X server, like the same user you have logged in before starting your Terminal session (`admin` and `root` accounts usually do not have out of the box access)

```bash
xcode-select --install
```

A dialog box will pop up, confirm, and after install you should be ready.